# How i can get value from radio button form in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

### Question.php

```
<?php
include 'Pre-function.php'

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Start.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="nav">
    <a href="Homepage.php">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div> 

<div class="question"> 
    <div class="A4">
        <form action="Answer.php" method="post">
            <?php getQuestion($conn);  ?>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
     </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Its html page to ask question

### Pre-function.php

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';

function getQuestion($conn) {

$query = "SELECT * FROM question ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if($result){
    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
       $question_id = $row['question_id'];
       $question_body = $row['question_body'];
       $option_a = $row['option_a'];
       $option_b = $row['option_b'];
        
        echo '  
        <h2 class="qtitle">'.$question_body.'</h2>
        <label for='.$question_body.'>Yes</label>
            <input type="radio" name="'.$question_id.'" value="Yes">
            <input type="hidden" name="option_a" value="'.$option_a.'">

        <label for="'.$question_body.'">No</label>
            <input type="radio" name="'.$question_id.'" value="No">
            <input type="hidden" name="option_b" value="'.$option_b.'">
        
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="submitted"><hr>';
        
        }
    
}

}

?>
```

Basically this form asked question whether `yes or no` using radio button. `$option_a == 'Yes'` and `$option_b == 'No'`. The question is like this "Are you have fever ?". So when i submit the value did not pass to the 'Answer.php' page.

### 'Answer.php' page.

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';

if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !empty($_POST['Submit'])){

      echo $_POST['option_a'];
      echo 'succeed';
}
else{

     echo 'no data';    
}

?>
```

In this page have error undefined_index value but still echo succeed.

Comment: Do a `print_r($_POST);` on Answer.php to know which indexes are passed and which to use.

Comment: Your while loop code is terrible, please fix it. Your code is creating a form on each loop but closing only the last one. This will mess everything!

Comment: @KarloKokkak don't you think it's a bad idea, putting the form tag inside `while loop`? Shouldn't the `<form></form>` be outside loop?

Comment: It's not as far as I know. But I think it's better to take the open `<form>` tag outside the while loop instead.

Comment: The closing `form tag` and `submit button` can also just be inserted inside the while loop instead so each question has its own form.

Comment: i already editted form tag out of while loop and tried using print_r its say 'unexpected $_POST(T_VARIABLE)'

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code should look like the following:

```
<input type="radio" name="whatevername" value="Yes">
<input type="hidden" name="whatevername" value="No">
```

You can use PHP to insert whatever values you want but you need the radio button name to be the same. 
Then if you want to echo that in PHP you'd use:

```
echo $_POST['whatevername']; //same name you used in the form
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing value as name for radio buttons

```
 name="'.$option_a.'"
```

This will result you in name ="Yes"

And you are trying to fetch `echo $_POST['option_a'];` where `option_a` is not defined.

Try this

```
<input type="radio" name="'.$question_id.'" value="Yes">
<input type="hidden" name="option_a" value="'.$option_a.'">
```

Same for other radio button

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this one :

    <?php
include 'conn.php';

function getQuestion($conn) {

$query = "SELECT * FROM question ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if($result){
    echo '<div class="A4">';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $question_id = $row['question_id'];
        $question_body = $row['question_body'];
        $option_a = $row['option_a'];
        $option_b = $row['option_b'];

        echo '
        <div class="A4">   
        <h2 class="qtitle">'.$question_body.'</h2>
        <form action="Answer.php" method="post">
            <label for='.$question_body.'>Yes</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radioQuestions[]" value="'.$question_id.'-'.$option_a.'">

            <label for="'.$question_body.'">No</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radioQuestions[]" value="'.$question_id.'-'.$option_b.'">

            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="submitted"><hr>';

    }
    echo'
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        </div>';
}

}

?>

<?php
include 'conn.php';

if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && !empty($_POST['submitted'])){
     $questionAndOptions = $_POST['radioQuestions'];

     foreach ($questionAndOptions as $questionAndOption) {
        $arrQuestionAndOption =  explode("-", $questionAndOption);
         echo $arrQuestionAndOption[0]; //question
         echo $arrQuestionAndOption[1]; //option
     }


      echo 'succeed';
}
else{

     echo 'no data';    
}

?>
```

Comment: Is it radioQuestion[ ] creating a array ? and i do not understand this ' value="'.$question_id.'-'.$option_a.'" '